# sudo: maas-import-pxe-files: command not found

Tags: maas

I installed Ubuntu 12.04 MAAS and tried to run `sudo maas-import-pxe-files` command as directed in the documentation, but I get the following:

```
sudo: maas-import-pxe-files: command not found
```

How can I run (sudo maas-import-pxe-files)?

I'm connected to the INTERNET and I'm the admin of the machine.

Answer (score 1):

I think in 12.04 the command you need is `sudo maas-import-isos` 
 `maas-import-pxe-files`  is 12.10 I think.

I followed [this tutorial](http://fafadiatech.blogspot.com/2012/04/metal-as-service-maas-for-cloud.html) for my 12.04 MAAS setup and it worked me

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same exact problem on 12.04. What fixes it is upgrading to 12.10. The documentation on MAAS is outdated and I found out the hard way after several hours of research. Hope that works for you!

maas-import-isos is used for a different purpose I believe, but still needed to do a slave install.